# ng-model not adding default checked checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get all the checked checkboxes from the ng-model, but the one that were checked by default are not being added to the model:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,a) in arr" class="checkbox" name="myArray[]">
     <label>
         <input ng-init="" ng-checked ="checkInArray(a.id, array2) == '1'"  type="checkbox" value="a.id" ng-value="a.id" ng-model ="m.names[a.id]" >{{a.title}} 
     </label>
</div>
```

In Angularjs:

```
$scope.checkInArray = function(v, array){
    var checked;

angular.forEach(array, function(value, key){

  if(v == array[key]['id']){
    checked= '1';
  }

});
return checked;

};
```

the function is working fine and the checkboxes that i want are getting selected by default but on submit the model is not taking the defaultly checked, I have to uncheck and check again.
Whats wrong here?

Comment: Don't use ng-checked to check a checkbox and hope the ng-model will change. Instead, make sure the ng-model contains the right value, and the checkbox will be checked accordingly. The model is the single point of truth. If you want a checkbox to be checked, then its ng-model must be falsy. If you want it unchecked, then its ng-model must be truthy. Note that there is no documentation for ngChecked and ngValue in the documentation. Read it.

Comment: ngValue: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue